# tcl permissions, called from PHP

Tags: php, permissions, tcl

I have the following files:
1. A TCL file that runs rsync using exec.
2. A PHP file that is called from a website (user interface), which passes on arguments to the TCL file (directory paths, mainly). I tested it several times from the website, and the arguments are passed successfully to the TCL file (they are echoed successfully in the TCL).

Here's the issue: When I run the TCL file from the command line (and pass arguments manually), rsync runs great. When I run the TCL file from PHP and pass the arguments, I get an error:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(601) [sender]
```

My gut tells me it is a permission issue - but which? I tried playing with chmods and chowns but to no avail.

EDIT:
Here's a snippet of the code. In short, a user logs into a web portal with a user interface, where a javascript allows the user to select a file for later remote execution (groundwater model). The javascript posts the selected file name to an intermediate PHP script. The login user name is similar to the directory name where the files for the model reside. Here are short versions of the codes. PHP:

```
//PHP Code:    
$username = <hardwired at this point>;    
$selRun = $_POST["script"]; //retrieved successfully from javascript
exec("tclsh run.tcl ".$username." ".$selRun." >> files/".$username."/.status.txt 2>&1");
```

The TCL file is quite long, but here are the key parts. The user name is the same as the directory that is referenced. And again, the arguments are successfully passed to the TCL from PHP:

```
# TCL Code:    
    set dirName [lindex $argv 0]
    set fileName [lindex $argv 1]
    set $key <some file>
    set CPString [format {rsync -lptgoDvz  --rsh="sshpass -f %s ssh" /<local path>/%s/*.* <user>@<someIP>:/<remote path>/%s/} $key $dirName $dirName]
    catch {exec >&@stdout bash <<$CPString}
```

Lastly, could it be a permission issue on the remote computer?

Comment: I'm assuming an HTTP request to your PHP script is executing this process...Can you post your PHP code executing your script IE: exec('tcl_script')  or passthru('tcl_script') etc... Thanks

Comment: It looks like permission issue as you have deduced it. When you are in ssh and run the command, the rsync has permission but when php script executes it, rsync would get it's permission from what ever the user php is running as (in most cases something like www-data if apache)

Comment: Also take a look at this - https://askubuntu.com/a/716911, are you using absolute path in your php script?

Comment: What does `ls -l` on the Tcl script report?

Comment: It's probably not permissions of the files on your local machine. I'd suspect your www user cannot ssh to the remote machine. Have you got the ssh keys set up for your www user?

Comment: Also, show the rsync command you use (with all the options) in your question.

Comment: Glenn, the tcl script has the following permissions: -rwxr-xr-x virtual virtual